# Mac Event Loop Qt Plugin in a non-Qt Application

Tags: macos, qt, events, qtplugin

I am trying to write a Trolltech Qt library that will be used from a *non-Qt CFM*/ Application written in MacApp.

I am having trouble that when I have created `QApplication` it is taking over my event loop in my non-Qt MacApp mac application. I have override `QApplication::macEventFilter` to call `CallNextEventHandler` but this calls my *Carbon Event Handler* in the MacApp Application but events like selecting a menu item do not work yet hot keys to the same item work fine.

I am in desperate need to figure this out. Is there a Mac Version of QMFCApp ?
I need to get this to work and get it to work the right way. Button clicks and menu items do not seem to work but other events such as typing seem to function. I think I some how need to deal with old `EventRecord` events and repost the event but I am not sure.

How do I get Qt to work as a plugin in my old Application ? Please help I am desperate.

Grant Hickey

Comment: JFYI, it's written as Qt, not QT.

Comment: I have no clue about Mac development, but there are basically two ways to integrate another event loop with Qt: using QApplication::processEvents and related to integrate Qt's loop within your own or replacing your own event loop with Qt's using QAbstractEventDispatcher. Check out http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtmotifextension/index.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051333/combing-an-external-event-loop-with-qts.

Answer (score 1):

Is it correct you are trying to develop an application for Mac OS 9?  MacApp has been discontinued for almost a decade and it seems like you're trying to mash together technologies that really aren't meant to be mixed.

Perhaps you could describe what you are trying to do at a higher level, and what your constraints are? I expect there must be an easier way using more modern bits.