# Qt: Writing plugins for other applications

Tags: qt, plugins, shared-libraries

I am writing a plugin for another application. I want to support the plugin on multiple platforms, so I am strongly considering using Qt.

The plugin needs to be able to show some basic GUI. The plugin interface does not in any way handle GUI - it is just a simple DLL/shared library specified with a C-header file.

Can I use Qt inside such a shared library? The calling application might or might not be using Qt itself. Any hints on what to do? Do I need to run a QApplication event-loop in a separate thread? Or can I just call the event-loop myself while waiting for input? (I only need modal dialogs).

Comment: Why not accept the answers to some of your other Qt questions? I know for a fact that at least one of them, the QtCreator/MSVC one, had good answers.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I was putting it off, since there were several good answers and it was hard selecting a "best" one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible because you need to create the [QApplication eventloop in the main thread](http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/4.5/threads.html#creating-a-thread).

> Note that QCoreApplication::exec()
>   must always be called from the main
>   thread (the thread that executes
>   main()), not from a QThread. In GUI
>   applications, the main thread is also
>   called the GUI thread because it's the
>   only thread that is allowed to perform
>   GUI-related operations.

Comment: I could start a non-QT thread to host the QApplication. It is probably not supported, but I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Here is a discussion of a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051333/combing-an-external-event-loop-with-qts